# FATAL EXCEPTION: DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.accentra.retrivedatabase.User

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have created a firebase realtime database I am trying to retrieve data using recycler view but I am getting error as below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.accentra.retrivedatabase, PID: 14196
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.accentra.retrivedatabase.User
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:418)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:203)
        at com.accentra.retrivedatabase.UserDetailActivity$1.onDataChange(UserDetailActivity.java:77)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.1.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14196 SIG: 9
Process 14196 terminated.
```

[image: The screenshot of my firebase database]

This is my code for Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;

public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://retrive-database-8f64a.firebaseio.com/";

Firebase firebase;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

// Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
public static final String Database_Path = "User";

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(MainActivity.this);
    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);


    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserDetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is the code for User detail activity

```
public class UserDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
Firebase firebase;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(UserDetailActivity.this));

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserDetailActivity.this);

    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

    progressDialog.show();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.Database_Path);

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                list.add(user);
            }

            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(UserDetailActivity.this,list);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the code for Recycler View Adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


Context context;
List<User> MainImageUploadInfoList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<User> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context = context;



}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.FirstNameTextView.setText(user.getFirst_name());

    holder.LastNameTextView.setText(user.getLast_name());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   public TextView FirstNameTextView;
   public TextView LastNameTextView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        FirstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        LastNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    }
}
}
```

And this is my User class

```
public class User {

private String first_name;
private String last_name;

public User() {
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```java
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Database_Path);
```

instead of:

```java
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);
```

Comment: What is the difference between this two?

Comment: In the second one, you try to read directly from the database root. In the first one, you specify to go into the "User" path.

Comment: According database structure [**Image**], both give me the same result. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I think you are wrong, Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652686/2637449

Comment: Well, there must be some kind of difference between both. But I am not able to give you a definite answer. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51340121/12154124

Comment: I want to ask that if i add a node i.e. User->User1->all->first name  in above firebase structure instead of User->User1-->first name what are the changes i can do?